# How can i receive messages from a form in my website

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Recently I have made my website using HTML,CSS and JavaScript.I have added on the bottom of my page a form with 3 inputs (name, email, message) for my visitor to fill in.I want somehow to receive these infos to my email.
I have search through the internet but i can not understand how i connect my html file of my website with an app using node which will run my server locally i suppose.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If you have, please include your code.

Comment: no i haven't because i don't know the way to do it

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a framework like Express for Node.js interactions. So the first thing you would have to do is install it:

```
npm install express
```

And this example, I'll install an additional middleware, called body-parser.

```
npm install body-parser  //  which would do this for you. body-parser parses your request and converts it into a format from which you can easily extract relevant information that you may need
```

Make a simple server to handle your POST requests, like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

app.post('/formData', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`Data from form :${req.body.name} ${req.body.lname}${req.body.message}.`);
});

const port = 8080;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Your server is running on port${port}`);
});
```

And in your HTML form: you can send data to the localhost [http:// 127.0.0.1], port 8080 and a route of /formData --> which is configured in Express server

```
<form action="http://localhost:8080/formData" method="POST">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
 <button type="submit">Send to backend</button>
</form>
```

You can actually check the below link for creating a node.js server:

https://dev.to/miku86/nodejs-how-to-create-a-simple-server-using-express-1n9d

Comment: Thank you very much!!!One question though.Is it possible to receive this data anytime?I mean that my local server app most of the time will be closed but my website is running all the time..

Comment: You need to host this backend service as you are wanting to create node server. You can use any cloud instance or heroku. However, it might cost you based on your usage for this.  Please follow these steps: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple choices. Your first option would be using the mailto link where the user can send you an email. Your second option can be that you use the sms link where the user can send you an sms message.

Answer (score 0):

Use third-party form apps like [Google Forms](https://form.new) or [Microsoft Forms](https://forms.microsoft.com), then use the “embed code”.